# Leap second Bug 31st Dec 2016

Tags: linux, rhel, linux-kernel, ntp

I just wanted to understand in a better way regarding the leap second bug.

1. Our Linux servers receive time from the windows PDC services, As per the update from the Microsoft regarding the leap second, time difference is resolved at the next time synchronization. since our Linux machines are polling time from windows PDC services via NTP should we have to worry? Also, these PDC services are synchronized with the NTP device located in central London which is using BST, as per the leap second announcement from Redhat, it's mentioned that this would affect only UTC, so I just wanted to know whether do we have to make any changes on our server.
2. Also, this leap second bug affects server via devices syncing with NTP server, then what about the server which is not connected to the server, how do those servers handle the leap second...

Comment: What is the leap second bug? Linux clocks operate on an integer counter disregarding leap seconds. A Linux day will always have the same number of clock increments regardless of whether a leap second has been added or removed or not. As far as I know, adjusting the machines clock during a time synchronization involves running the counter faster or slower for a short period of time to match up with the time source – without disturbing continuity. Unless you have a very good reason (in which case you should already know instead of ask), you shouldn't need to be concerned about leap seconds.

Comment: @Robin479 I guess OP has reason to be concerned as he is synchronizing from NTP servers running on Windows.

Comment: A Windows problem? ;)

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333179/ .  RedHat is splashing this in amber with exclamation marks across the top of the main page of its customer WWW site.  Hence people responding like this.

Comment: By the way, if one has a time server in central London that is currently on British Summer Time, only a week after the Winter Solstice, one has _actual_ problems with one's time servers.

Answer (score -3):

Leap second change/update doesn’t cause any problem unless you have an application that work/check in second level, normaly all application are use minute time

http://www.windowstricks.in/2015/06/is-leap-second-impact-windows-servers-and-application.html